# Is it possible to combine multiple files of different file types to a single PDF file in PHP?

Tags: php, pdf-generation, laravel-5.1

I am using laravel framework version 5.1. My requirement is to upload multiple files of types doc, docx, pdf and to save this file as a single PDF file. I have found packages that can combine/edit PDF files. But is there any library/package available for laravel to  do this with doc/docx files too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that LibreOffice allows command line conversion using the LibreOffice conversion engine (which DID preserve the formatting like I wanted and generally worked great).

```
libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf fileToConvert.docx -outdir output/path/for/pdf
```

But I didn't have admin rights on my host's web server.

Then I ran across a cool project made by a Ph.D. student (Philip J. Guo) at Stanford called [CDE(Code Data Environment)](http://www.pgbovine.net/cde.html). In short, it allows one to avoid dependency hell by copying all the files used when you run certain commands, recreating the linux environment where the command worked. I was able to use this to run LibreOffice without having to resort to someone's portable version of it, and it worked just like it did when I did it on Ubuntu with the command above, with a tweak: I needed to run the wrapper of LibreOffice the CDE generated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a catch all package to do this but as i can not comment yet (just joined), here is how i would do it.

upload the files using using your form and controller do your validation, storage etc. 
Then pass an array of the paths to the files you have uploaded to a blade template and embed them on the page depending on the file type.

This package 
https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf

Can convert a html template to a pdf.

Hope it points you in the right direction

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf');

$files = ['your file paths'];

$pdf->loadView('template.path', ['files' => $files])->setPaper('A4')->setOrientation('portrait');
    return $pdf->stream('download.pdf');
```

Comment: But will this work for pdf files uploaded. We need an iframe to render the pdf in HTML. Iframe cannot be streamed to a PDF again right?